# Differential forms as tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

We can define differential k-forms at point $p$ of manifold $M$ to be elements of $\Lambda^k(T^*_pM)$. However, as $\Lambda^k(T^*_pM)\subset\Lambda(T^*_pM)=\frac{T(T^*_pM)}{I}$ elements of k-th exterior power are equivalence classes.
**Question:** How do we make tensors our of this equivalence classes?

I know there is a map: $i:\Lambda^k(V)\to T^k(V)$
$[v_1] \wedge\dots\wedge [v_k]\mapsto\sum_\sigma(sgn(\sigma))v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dots \otimes v_{\sigma(k)}$
But is this map chooses representative from each class uniquely? I mean you can always pick from the class arbitrary representative, how do you know which one should you pick for this map to well-defined.

For example: we can look at particular element of $\Lambda^2(V)$, say this one: $[a\otimes b+c\otimes d+e\otimes f]$. How do I extract exact tensor from this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any vector space $V$, there is a canonical map $$\textrm{Alt} : T^k V^* \to T^k V^*$$ defined by 
$$(\textrm{Alt}\, \phi)(X_1, \ldots, X_k) := \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} (\textrm{sgn}\, \sigma) \phi(X_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots X_{\sigma(k)}) .$$ For any $\phi$, $\textrm{Alt}\,\phi$ is *alternating*; a $k$-form form $\psi$ is alternating iff for all $\sigma \in S_k$ we have
$$\psi(X_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, X_{\sigma(k)}) = (\textrm{sgn}\,\sigma) \psi(X_1, \ldots, X_k) .$$
With this definition, we can give the characterization you ask about: Under your identification of $\Lambda^k V^*$ as a quotient of $T^k V^*$, checking the definition shows that $i(\omega)$ is alternating, so $i$ maps an element of $\Lambda^k V^*$ to the unique representative $\phi$ of $\Lambda^k V^*$ in $T^k V^*$ such that $\phi$ is alternating, that is, such that $\textrm{Alt}\,\phi = \phi$. Since $i$ is injective, we may identify $\Lambda^k V^*$ with $\textrm{im}\, i$, and hence as a vector subspace of $T^k V^*$, which is how we usually regard it.

One can check that $\textrm{Alt}$ is idempotent, that is, that $\textrm{Alt} \circ \textrm{Alt} = \textrm{Alt}$ (it is, in fact, a vector space projection in $T^k V^*$), so to find the representative $i([\omega])$ of a class $[\omega]$, we can simply compute $\textrm{Alt} \, \omega$ for any representative $\omega \in [\omega]$. Applying the definition for $k = 2$ gives
$$(\textrm{Alt}\, \omega)(X_1, X_2) = \frac{1}{2}(\omega(X_1, X_2) - \omega(X_2, X_1)),$$ or, for $\alpha, \beta \in V^*$,
$$\textrm{Alt}(\alpha \otimes \beta) = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha \otimes \beta - \beta \otimes \alpha) .$$

(I should add that the above formulation must be modified if the field underlying $V$ has positive characteristic $\leq k$. In that case, $k! = 0$, so our formula for $\textrm{Alt}$ and the rest of our treatment must be modified.)

Comment: Thank you! Also, is alterntaion responsible for killing in the sum all of the terms from ideal $I$?

Comment: You're welcome, and though you don't say how $I$ is defined, it is probably $\ker i$, which gives (under the identification in the answer) a natural direct sum decomposition $T^k V = \ker i \oplus \Lambda^k V$. For $k = 1$, $\ker i = \{0\}$, and for $k = 2$, $\ker i = \smash{\bigodot^2 V}$, the space of *symmetric* $2$-tensors in $T^2 V$.

Comment: I have edited the answer to write things instead of the vector space dual $V^*$, so that the $X_a$ are vectors rather than covectors, but this preserves the spirit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just got confused about how everywhere in the literature wedge product is used directly on representatives of equivalence classes rather than on the classes itself. Now I see that there is one-to-one correspondence. Can we say that $i(\Lambda^k(V))$ is isomorphic to $\Lambda^k(V)$ ? So under this isomorphism we can directly apply wedge product on representatives.

Comment: Yes, that's right, $i$ is injective and hence a vector space isomorphism onto its image. In fact, it follows from the characterization in the answer that $i$ is (up to a multiplicative factor of $k!$) the map induced by $\textrm{Alt} : T^k V^* \to T^k V^*$ via the quotient map $T^k V^* \to \Lambda^k V^*$. In some (most?) contexts, $\Lambda^k V$ is introduced as a subspace of $T^k V$, not as a quotient of it.